# Is it possible to enable Windows Mixed Reality on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, virtual-reality

Windows Mixed Reality (WMR) isn’t shipped with Windows Server 2019, which I'm currently running at version 1809.

Is there an update or a PowerShell command that will allow a Windows Mixed Reality (WMR) device to be recognised on this system?

Comment: I'm new in this community and would really appreciate feedback or comments on how to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Windows Server 2019 is not part of the Windows Mixed Reality supported versions

Seems like Windows Server 2019 does not support Windows Mixed Reality as of yet. As explained in [this official Microsoft document for Windows Mixed Reality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/enthusiast-guide/before-you-start#make-sure-you-have-the-windows-10-version-1709-or-newer-installed):

> Make sure you have the Windows 10 Version 1709 or newer installed
> You must be running the Windows 10 Version 1903 or newer to use Windows Mixed Reality. Compatible versions of Windows 10 include:
>
> - Windows 10 Version 1903
> - Windows 10 Version 1909
> - Windows 10 Version 2004
> - Windows 10 Version 20H2
>
> To see which version of Windows 10 your device is currently running, select the Start button, then select **Settings > System > About**.
>
> To ensure that Windows 10 is up to date on your PC, select the **Start** button, then select **Settings > Update & security > Windows Update**. Select Check for updates. If updates are available, install them.